# Wrong pattern for validate a several rules

Tags: regex

I need to develop a pattern regex for this rules:

The first character must be a letter.

At least one number.

At least one capital letter.

At least one lowercase letter.

At least one symbol (can be any of these: `$, @, #, *, /, &, !, ¿, ?, ¡, +, -, %, (, ), =`)

You must be 8 characters.

I have this pattern but it is not working:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

u would try it **REGEX**

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(\D\W)){8,}.+$
```

**:D**

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[$@#*\/&!¿?¡+%()=-])[a-zA-Z](?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9$@#*\/&!¿?¡+%()=-]{7}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NP4oCe/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - there must be at least 1 uppercase ASCII letter somewhere to the right in the string
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - there must be at least 1 lowercase ASCII letter somewhere to the right in the string
- `(?=.*[$@#*\/&!¿?¡+%()=-])` - there must be at least one char from the character class somewhere to the right in the string
- `[a-zA-Z]` - the first char is an ASCII letter
- `(?=.*[0-9])` - there must be at least one digit somewhere to the right in the string
- `[A-Za-z0-9$@#*\/&!¿?¡+%()=-]{7}`  - 7 chars, letter, digits, special chars from the char class
- `$` -  end of string.

Note that if you allow *any* chars in the string, replace `[A-Za-z0-9$@#*\/&!¿?¡+%()=-]{7}` with `.{7}`.